# Workaround for AppCenter not allowing Xamarin UI Tests to call a browser?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I'm writing Xamarin UI Tests to test our sign up screens. As part of this process the user would have to confirm that the email address they provided was valid. An email would be sent to the user and they would have to click a link in that email, the user could then return to our app and continue the sign up process.

In the [General Tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/troubleshooting/) section this MS App center document it says...

`Test can't automate multiple apps, or system apps (browser, camera, and so on). This limitation is true even for testing frameworks that allow full system control locally.`

To be clear here in [issue 287](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/287) from an MS Employee ..

`Also, you noted "Browser [e.g. stock browser, safari] All", just to be clear, Xamarin.UITest can only automate your own app, and WebViews contained within your App Sandbox. If your app launches the system browser, for example; then Xamarin.UITest is not able to automate that.`

I'd rather not have to change the code in our app with a backdoor.
I'm sure I'm likely to reach another similar issue which a backdoor wouldn't fix.

So I'm looking to workaround this problem, has anyone come up with anything ?

I'm guessing this solution would involve adding more functionality to the test app.

Answer (score 0):

My plan is to upload a build of our app that simulates communication with our web api. Or at the very least you could create a build of the app that points to a special version of your api that skips this check. The special version of the API is not used for production, just for UI testing.